# script order for jquery with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to jquery and bootstrap, and I can't get them to play nicely with each other. I have a page with both bootstrap dropdowns and jquery sliders.  However, I can't get both of them to work at the same time.

**Bootstrap dropdowns work with this file, and sliders break**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="/js/slider_input.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
....
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

</body
</html
```

By removing the second to last line like so:

**Sliders work, and bootstrap dropdowns break**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="/js/slider_input.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
....

    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

</body
</html
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

oh yeah now i see sorry. You have to load your actual jquery first, else UI won't work either. So this should be the head

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/js/slider_input.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Also in html5 you need to leave off the 'type="text/javascript"', like the bootstrap one, also be consisten, so if you have it on the other, also add it to the bootstrap, it has to do with loading rules.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but it seems like your Bootstrap version requires a newer version of jQuery to run properly, try to replace:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

with

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then leaving it off in your body.

Let me know what happens then.

**Note:** *Don't ever load* two jQuerys, they will break and stop the working of your functions, and especially when you use ajax on your page.

Comment: One of those is for jqueryui and one is from jquery, don't I need both?

Comment: Tried it anyway and it's still broken :(

Comment: oh yeah now i see sorry. You have to load your actual jquery first, else UI won't work either.

So this should be the head
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 1):

"jQuery must come first,
  then Popper.js, and then our [bootstrap]
  JavaScript plugins."
[Bootstrap 4.x javascript script order: getbootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js)