# Can't get <script type="text/javascript"> to work in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, unity-game-engine, types

I am trying to cut and paste some code into Bootstrap that is generated by the Unity3D game engine (for embedding its player in a web page).  I am using the Dreamweaver Bootstrap template.  Bootstrap hangs on this code:

```
    <script src='https://ssl-webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/jquery.min.js'  type='text/javascript' ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

I got a hint from this post, [Bootstrap Dropdowns...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926086/script-order-for-jquery-with-bootstrap), and I put the "script src" before the "script type" which fixed the first line of code.  But Bootstrap still hangs on the second line and the Unity player won't load without it.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Thanks.
Zaffer

*****edit******

Thanks Pomax and Slick,  The problem is indeed with trying to use HTML4 code in HTML5 Bootstrap.  I am taking the liberty of posting the whole Unity3D code here in hopes you or someone else out there will help me find a way to  translate it into HTML5 code that works and downloads the player.  I would be grateful for any help or suggestions -- code, pointers to tutorials, etc.  I'm pretty good with HTML4, have a nodding acquaintance with CSS, Noob to Bootstrap.  Thanks.
Zaffer

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Unity Web Player | SummersDay</title>

        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ssl-webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        var unityObjectUrl = "http://webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/UnityObject2.js";
        if (document.location.protocol == 'https:')
            unityObjectUrl = unityObjectUrl.replace("http://", "https://ssl-");
        document.write('<script type="text\/javascript" src="' + unityObjectUrl + '"><\/script>');
        -->
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
            jQuery(function() {
                var config = {
                    width: "100%", 
                    height:  "100%",
                    params: {disableContextMenu: "true"}
                };
                var u = new UnityObject2(config);

                var $missingScreen = jQuery("#unityPlayer").find(".missing");
                var $brokenScreen = jQuery("#unityPlayer").find(".broken");
                $missingScreen.hide();
                $brokenScreen.hide();

                u.observeProgress(function (progress) {
                    switch(progress.pluginStatus) {
                        case "broken":
                            $brokenScreen.find("a").click(function (e) {
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                e.preventDefault();
                                u.installPlugin();
                                return false;
                            });
                            $brokenScreen.show();
                        break;
                        case "missing":
                            $missingScreen.find("a").click(function (e) {
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                e.preventDefault();
                                u.installPlugin();
                                return false;
                            });
                            $missingScreen.show();
                        break;
                        case "installed":
                            $missingScreen.remove();
                        break;
                        case "first":
                        break;
                    }
                });
                u.initPlugin(jQuery("#unityPlayer")[0], "Story_mesh_baker Build.unity3d");
            });
        -->
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        <!--
                    /* hide from ie on mac \*/
        html {
        height:100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        }
            /* end hide */

        body {
            font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
        a:link, a:visited {
            color: #000;
        }
        a:active, a:hover {
            color: #666;
        }
        p.header {
            font-size: small;
        }
        p.header span {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        p.footer {
            font-size: x-small;
        }
        div.content {
            margin: auto;
            width: 100%;
            height:100%;
        }
        div.broken,
        div.missing {
            margin: auto;
            position: relative;
            top: 50%;
            width: 193px;
        }
        div.broken a,
        div.missing a {
            height: 63px;
            position: relative;
            top: -31px;
        }
        div.broken img,
        div.missing img {
            border-width: 0px;
        }
        div.broken {
            display: none;
        }
        div#unityPlayer {
            cursor: default;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        embed {
            width:100% !important;
        }
        -->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="content">
            <div id="unityPlayer">
                <div class="missing">
                    <a href="http://unity3d.com/webplayer/" title="Unity Web Player. Install now!">
                        <img alt="Unity Web Player. Install now!" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/installation/getunity.png" width="193" height="63" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="broken">
                    <a href="http://unity3d.com/webplayer/" title="Unity Web Player. Install now! Restart your browser after install.">
                        <img alt="Unity Web Player. Install now! Restart your browser after install." src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/installation/getunityrestart.png" width="193" height="63" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why can't you use jQuery from some officially mentioned CDNs?

Comment: the code you're showing has an HTML4 style script element start tag, then an end tag, and then another HTML4 style script element start tag. HTML5 does not use `type=...` if the script is for JavaScript source.

Comment: Thanks Pomax and CDN.  I took the liberty of posting the code from Unity3D in hopes you or someone can help me translate it to HTML5 that will still work with the Unity player.  Any help at all will be very much appreciated.